# Swipe many elements

Tags: angularjs, carousel, swipe

Is it possible to make swipe in angularjs in carousel mode? I mean, many examples of angular swipe contains only one item shown and all others are hidden. Is it possible to make in Angularjs something like that? [See an example](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/demos/main-demos/06-carousel-mode.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and there is already a directive/module called angular-carousel set up for that!

[angular-carousel](http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-carousel)

I've used this on several projects and it works really well.  Not only that, but you can preload images as you swipe.